# How to fix this code? i tried WITH statement but it gave me an error

Tags: mysql, database, with-statement, erd

I tried to answer this question here in the code below, but it keeps giving me an error message!
I've tried to figure out how to
**Provide the name of the sales_rep in each region with the largest amount of total_amt_usd sales**?

and it gave me this Error :

> *aggregate function calls cannot be nested*
> [ERD picture here](https://shiguelita.github.io/img/notebook/post005_udacity.png)

could you please help me with this?

```
WITH 
    account_info AS (Select * from accounts),
    orders_info AS (select * from orders),
    region_info AS (select * from region),
    sales_reps_info AS (select * from sales_reps)
    
    SELECT s.name as rep_name, r.name as region_name, MAX (SUM (o.total_amt_usd)) as total
    FROM orders_info o
    JOIN account_info a
    ON o.account_id = a.id
    
    JOIN sales_reps_info s
    ON a.sales_rep_id = s.id
    
    JOIN region_info r
    ON r.id = s.region_id
    
    GROUP BY TOTAL, REP_NAME, R.NAME
    ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the whole table there is no need for WITH

```
SELECT s.name as rep_name, r.name as region_name, MAX (SUM (o.total_amt_usd)) as total
    FROM orders o
    JOIN account a
    ON o.account_id = a.id
    
    JOIN sales_reps s
    ON a.sales_rep_id = s.id
    
    JOIN region r
    ON r.id = s.region_id
    
    GROUP BY TOTAL, REP_NAME, R.NAME
    ORDER BY 3 DESC
    LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are attempting with `with` since you don't actually define a Common Table Expression.

That aside, your query is invalid, you cannot *nest* aggregate functions and you are already getting the *max* 100 by ordering and limiting rows, so I think you just want

```
SELECT s.name as rep_name, r.name as region_name, SUM (o.total_amt_usd) as Total
FROM orders_info o
JOIN account_info a ON o.account_id = a.id
JOIN sales_reps_info s ON a.sales_rep_id = s.id
JOIN region_info r ON r.id = s.region_id
GROUP BY REP_NAME, R.NAME
ORDER BY Total DESC
LIMIT 100;
```